# Differences between C++11, C# and Java memory models

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, memory-management, c++11

I know that C++11 memory model was inspired from Java memory model, but there has to be something that differentiates both these memory models.

```
Java uses synchronize and mutexes
C++11 uses atomics and mutexes
C# uses volatile
```

But what are the fundamental differences between these three in terms of multithreading in memory and in terms of read/write accesses for threads? Which memory model is better out of those three models? Can anyone please shed a light on this topic(only the differences) in detailed manner or provide a link that i can refer to? And how efficiently can these implemented on various real time systems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this does not quantify the *differences* between the C++11 memory models, it does go into great detail about the C++11 model, which is the most recently codified, and therefore likely the most modern:

http://herbsutter.com/2013/02/11/atomic-weapons-the-c-memory-model-and-modern-hardware/

Once you understand C++11's model as a starting point, that will give you better tools for asking about other languages.